# Why is the attribute 'key' and 'vars' not recognised

Tags: vue.js, syntax-error, laravel-5.8, image-upload, vue-dropzone

```
public function store (Request $request)
{
    $images = request()->file ( key:'file');
    dd( ...vars: $images);
}
```

Is the key: and ...var: attribute not reccognized in Laravel 5.8, because it keeps throwing syntax error at me?

Answer (score 0):

Missing $ sign with those keywords!
Hope it helps.